# Event Problems with Control.Webbrowser in .NET 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a problem with this control. I can´t detect when is completely loaded(web page fully loaded). Another problem its when it changes the web pages goes to the same event and it makes a lot of errors and i can´t control it.
Here is the lines of code which are making the problem.

```
AddHandler browser.DocumentCompleted, AddressOf pageLoaded
    browser.Navigate("Web Address")
```

Here its pageLoaded Sub:

```
   Private Sub pageLoaded(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs) Handles browser.DocumentCompleted
    Dim autoHotkey As New Process()


    browser.Document.GetElementById("j_username").InnerText = "USER"
    browser.Document.GetElementById("j_password").InnerText = "PASS"
    browser.Document.GetElementById("loginbutton").InvokeMember("Click")
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
    MsgBox(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\aceptarAlerta.exe")
    autoHotkey.StartInfo.FileName = My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\aceptarAlerta.exe"
    autoHotkey.Start()
    autoHotkey.Close()
    autoHotkey.Dispose()


End Sub
```

It always running and runing and making errors cause i change the webpages and it can´t find these id´s.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this and it works.

```
Private Property paginaLista As Boolean = False
Private Sub WaitForPageLoad()
    AddHandler browser.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
    While Not paginaLista
        Application.DoEvents()
    End While
    paginaLista = False
End Sub

Private Sub PageWaiter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs)
    If browser.ReadyState = WebBrowserReadyState.Complete Then
        paginaLista = True

        RemoveHandler browser.DocumentCompleted, New WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(AddressOf PageWaiter)
    End If
End Sub
```